# Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: maven

I am trying to setup my project and I am using maven.
I am facing a issue which mvn eclipse:eclipse.
It gives error while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1
Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Can you please post your error stack trace?

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at: http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/

Answer (score 2):

This issue is usually caused when the source is developed compatible with JDK 8 or some other version.

But when the user tries to build & compile the code using the JDK higher than , from what it is actually developed.

To fix this - change to the compatible JDK version

[image: JDK version change]

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting JDK 17 then you can just replace

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            ...
```

with

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            ...
```

Reload the POM and recompile. It may apply to JDK 11 too, but I've never tried it.